# Why does using long as datatype make 'implicit conversion loses integer precision' disappear?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I know there are lots of questions with this title but i am not looking for a solution. I would like to know why this works.
I have this given as a solution

```
int points[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

int *pos = points + 5;

int index = pos - points;
```

but when i use that code i get the warning implicit conversion loses integer precision:'long' to 'int'. Now when i use long instead as datatype of index

```
int points[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

int *pos = points + 5;

long index = pos - points;
```

it gives no warning. I tried to use long because i remembered something about pointers and long. But Pointers do not have a datatype(if i am wrong please correct me). Both points and *pos are initialized with int. So why does long fit and int does not?

Why do they use int in the solution? Is the solution wrong or is it about xCode(which i am working with)?

Thank you for answering

Comment: pointers **do** have types, of course, but that's not relevant here. The correct type to use for a difference of two pointers is [`ptrdiff_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/ptrdiff_t)

Comment: `long` isn't guaranteed to work, e.g. it wouldn't work on 64bit windows.

Comment: Is `ptrdiff_t` in C, or only in C++?

Comment: It's C. cppreference.com has references for both languages. (it [also exists in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t))

Comment: @Gottaquest yes you do. Writing just the identifier of an array evaluates to a pointer to its first element. How else should `points + 5` make any sense?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> but when i use that code i get the warning implicit conversion loses integer precision:'long' to 'int'.

This means that **on your platform**, the difference of two pointers is of type `long`.

> I tried to use long because i remembered something about pointers and long. But Pointers do not have a datatype(if i am wrong please correct me).

You're wrong, everything has a type in C. Pointers have *pointer types*. The difference between two pointers is a signed integer type, but the standard doesn't specify which one, different platforms will use different types.

But the standard specifies a `typedef` by the name `ptrdiff_t` (defined in `stddef.h`) which must be defined to the signed integer type of a pointer difference, so this is the type you *should* use for the kind of code you show.

> Both points and *pos are initialized with int. So why does long fit and int does not?

The type pointers point to is something different than the pointers themselves. Pointers are addresses, and on your system, addresses can be larger than `int` values.

> Why do they use int in the solution? Is the solution wrong

Yes, it's wrong. As explained above, the expression `pos - points` is **some** signed integer type, and it might be an `int` on some platforms, but you can't assume that.

Of course, the following would be ok as well:

```
int points[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

int *pos = points + 5;

int index = (int)(pos - points);
```

In this example, you know the result can be represented in an `int`, so you can just convert it by an explicit cast. But don't do that *in general*.

Comment: thanks for the time you took to answer all my questions:) So i should use ptrdiff_t and define it to the signed integer type of a pointer difference(in my case long?). How would i do this?

Comment: `#include <stddef.h>`. The "*must be defined to the signed integer type of a pointer difference*" is a requirement towards an implementation of C. You just use it...

Comment: I don't get what you're asking? Just use `ptrdiff_t` ... :o

Comment: Ok i get that it is a requirement and that i have to include <stddef.h> as ptrdiff_t is defined in it. But i do not really get how i can define ptrdiff_t *to the signed integer type of a pointer difference*..could you write the code for doing that? Or do i have to use ptrdiff_t as type?

Comment: again, that's done in `stddef.h`. It's a requirement towards the *implementation of C* (ie the compiler and the standard library)

Comment: *You just use it*-what do i just use? -> ptrdiff_t - Where and how do i use it? I dont really get what to do with it but maybe thats because i dont know more about typedefs than i googled just before..

Comment: It's a `typedef` which is an alias for a type. So, use it just like any other type (instead of `long`).

Comment: Oh okay so i use 'typedef' every time i want to get a difference between two pointers?

Comment: I recommend you re-read answer, comments, and the link to the `ptrdiff_t` reference I posted. Take your time ...

Comment: I will. Thank you anyway for being patient.

Answer (score 6):

`index = pos - points;` is a subtraction between two pointers, where the type have to be `ptrdiff_t`.

Here is the description from the C11 standard Committee Draft N1570 § 6.5.6:

> 9 . When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of
>   the same array object, or one past the last element of the array
>   object; the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two
>   array elements. The size of the result is implementation-defined, and
>   its type **(a signed integer type)** is **ptrdiff_t** defined in the
>   `<stddef.h>` header.

In your system, it happens that the type `ptrdiff_t` is likely a `typedef` to `long` like mentioned in comments by @FelixPalmen, that's why the compiler is complaining when you declare `index` as `int`.

Comment: Good answer! Little nitpick: "*it happens that the type long can hold the ptrdiff_t*" <- more likely, on the system, `ptrdiff_t` **is** a `typedef` to `long`. Thumbs up for the relevant standard quote!

Comment: @FelixPalmen, yes that's right, I will edit my post :)

Comment: thank you for that (book?) excerpt (how did you find it so fast?) and the explanation which is really helpful:)

Comment: @Gottaquest, it is from the [C standard](https://web.cs.dal.ca/~vlado/pl/C_Standard_2011-n1570.pdf), and `Ctrl+F` can be very helpful :).

Comment: ..nice one now i feel dumb:)